# While cycle isn't reaching the end of a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning about data structures and I'm trying to create a linked list. My problem is that one of my two while cycles aren't reaching the end of the linked list (it stops in the first element). They're not exactly equal, but they're very similar; the first cycle (the working one) runs while the current list pointer isn't null, and the second runs while the the next list pointer isn't null. The compiler isn't showing any errors and the program doesn't stop working when opened. Also is important to say that this isn't my main code, it's a test code that I wrote to try to solve the problem myself (unfortunately, without success) - but it serves to illustrate the problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct List {
    int data;
    struct List *next;
} List;

int main(void) {
    system("cls");

    List *hook    = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)),
         *root1   = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)),
         *root2   = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)),
         *root3   = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)),
         *item    = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List)),
         *current = (List *) malloc(sizeof(List));

    hook->data = -20;
    hook->next = root1;

    root1->data = 10;
    root1->next = root2;

    root2->data = 20;
    root2->next = root3;

    root3->data = 30;
    root3->next = NULL;

    current = hook;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("\"First while\" data: %i\n", current->data);
        current = current->next;
    }
    // In this while cycle, the code goes through all the items of the linked list and print their data values correctly

    printf("\"Hook\" next: %i\n", hook->next);
    current = hook;

    printf("\"Current->next\" next: %i\n", current->next->next);

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current->next = current->next->next;
    }
    // On the other hand, in this while cycle the code stops in the first element of the list (hook);
    // consequently, it prints the first data value, but the intention was to get in the end of the list and print the last value

    printf("\"Second while\" data: %i\n", current->data);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[Picture of the terminal with the program output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jsON.png)

"Hook" and "Current->next" are purposely being displayed with "%i", just to verify if they aren't null. What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: To print a (`void *`) pointer with `printf` use the `%p` format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the loop

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current->next = current->next->next;
}
```

You *modify* the list, effectively removing all but the first node from the list.

If you want to only iterate over it to get the last node, you need to update `current` like normal:

```
while (current->next != NULL) {
    current = current->next;
}
```

Comment: Ok, now I understand. This is more a logical problem than a coding problem. Seems like I need to get better in this part. Thank you a lot!

Comment: @NathanMurillo When dealing with linked lists I always recommend using pencil and paper. Draw nodes as squares and pointers as arrows. Erase and redraw arrows as you perform operations on the list. Note that `current` would have *two* arrows: One for where `current` is pointing, and one for its `next` pointer.